Cross linking websites with millions of pages in the header of the websites generated a lot of spammy backlinks
I run a few websites with data about companies from public registries in the US in different states.
I thought it would be a good idea to add links in the header of the website with "Other States" without nofollow.
I haven't paid much attention when number of keywords in ahrefs started dropping (the traffic was growing).
In the last week, 2 of my websites got -95% in traffic, and a third on is on it's way (keywords started dropping also)
What I think the issue is that these links were on all the pages (they were in the header of the website), so it triggered a spam of backlinks (there are millions of pages on each of them, and about 10k get indexed every day on each website, this was on for 2 weeks).
I removed these links. Created a separated page for that with nofollow links between websites.
For reference, each website has 50-70k external backlinks in google search console from all other websites.
Question 1:
Is there any action I can do to fix this or speed up the process of fixing this.
Question 2:
There are a lot relations between states (ex. a company is a branch of a company in another state), where I have links between them. Am I safe if I put nofollow on them ?

Because the pages are not in error, there is nothing else that you can do.  You just have to wait patiently for Google to visit your site for at least a few times.
You are fine to put nofollow, but if you have too many such links, Google will probably penalize you. (I will find and post the reference tomorrow which from memory, does not distinguish between follow and nofollow).  You can get around it by having a local landing page which points to the other site.

The answer to the first question is.
Take the conditional Ahrefs or any other service for working with back links.
Check pages that have received a large number of links in a short period of time and recently. Pages with a spike in links are most likely unreliable sources of information.
Next, we collect this entire list in a file and upload it to Google Disavow Links in GSC to reject spam links.
As for the second question.
Yes, you can add nofollow to links between sites, especially if they represent relationships that may be perceived as spam.
But be sure to remember that nofollow links do not transmit the reference weight.
